# PHP ksort unexpected behavior

Tags: php, ksort

Let me tell you from the start: I know about the sort flags of this function. When I use `SORT_STRING` it works well, but the default flag `SORT_REGULAR` works weird, or doesn't work at all.

Consider an array like below.

```
$arr = [
    '27a'   => 'foo',
    '27b'   => 'foo',
    '27c'   => 'foo',
    '27'    => 'foo',
];
```

When I try to sort using ksort, it gives an array without being sorted in any obvious logic.

```
ksort($arr);

print_r($arr);

// this prints
Array
(
    [27a] => foo
    [27] => foo
    [27b] => foo
    [27c] => foo
)
```

As one could say the keys are neither **numerically** nor **alphanumerically** nor **naturally** sorted. Even more strangely, when I change the order of the source array, it gives a different result:

```
$arr = [
    '27a'   => 'foo',
    '27'    => 'foo',
    '27b'   => 'foo',
    '27c'   => 'foo',
];

ksort($arr);

print_r($arr);

// this prints
Array
(
    [27b] => foo
    [27c] => foo
    [27] => foo
    [27a] => foo
)
```

Does anyone know the logic behind this? Is this a bug or am I missing something?

EDIT: Thank you all for being interested in and answering my question. Although it's marked as duplicate, the other question didn't mention the weirder part: **Why changing the order of the source array changes the result? It should give the same result with the same input set.** Shall we discuss this too?

Comment: Thank you all for being interested in and answering my question. Although it's marked as duplicate, the other question didn't mention the weirder part: Why changing the order of the source array changes the result? It should give the same result with the same input set. Shall we discuss this too?

Answer (score 4):

The reason that is happening is because it sees keys like '27a' as a string, and keys like '27' as an integer, even though it is quoted. You'll see the same results if you remove the quotes from the 27 key.

And, as the [ksort page](http://php.net/ksort) says: "Warning: Be careful when sorting arrays with mixed types values because sort() can produce unpredictable results."

Weird behavior for sure- unfortunately the best way to produce expected results when you have keys that look like integers (even if they are strings), is to specify the sort flag like SORT_STRING to ensure that you get the expected results every time.

Comment: Thank you. I should face the fact that the definition of SORT_REGULAR from php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php isn't reliable at all: "SORT_REGULAR - compare items normally (don't change types)" It's falsely leading me to think it won't take numeric strings as integers.